# How to navigate to other page on Http POST API Success response?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I want to navigate to other page from Login screen on Post api success.  I have login screen making post api with params username and email.On Success method have to navigate to other page.Have seen some example but its confusing for me pls help me.

Comment: A sample of what you have written would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would look on [redux](http://redux.js.org/) and [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) which may help you with proper flow and state handling.

Answer (score 0):

I would use react-router and redux to display different as you say "screens" or routes in react-router speak.

When post api succeeds, appropriate action would get dispatched, and reducer for that action would change part of the state into something like:

`{loggedIn: true}`

Your login component would then when it finds `loggedIn:true` in state render itself as:

```
<Redirect to="/your-new-location" />
```